# Segmentation fault error after execution of c6accel sample

Tags: linux, memory, arm, texas-instruments, omap

I use OMAP-L138 Exp Kit. 
First please look at my U-boot properties.

There they are:

```
U-Boot > printenv
    baudrate=115200
    autoload=no
    bootcmd=run netboot
    bootfile=uImage-da850-omapl138-evm.bin
    filesize=204104
    fileaddr=C0700000
    rootpath=/home/my_name/targetfs
    netboot=tftpboot 0xc0700000 uImage-da850-omapl138-evm.bin; bootm 0xc0700000
    bootargs=console=ttyS2,115200n8 mem=64M root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.1.218:/home/my_name/targetfs ip=192.168.1.231
    netargs=console=ttyS2,115200n8 noinitrd rw mem=64M root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.1.218:/home/my_name/targetfs,nolock ip=192.168.1.231
    stdin=serial
    stdout=serial
    stderr=serial
    ver=U-Boot 2009.11 (Jan 13 2011 - 01:05:37)
    Environment size: 728/65532 bytes
```

In setup.sh of DVSDK I used next parameters: **board memory 64 mb**, Linux kernel location - TFTP, root file system location - NFS.
Making of DVSDK was succesfull. 
I made install in c6accel_1_01_00_07 directory too.

```
root@my_name-desktop:/usr/local/dvsdk/c6accel_1_01_00_07# make install
Creating /home/my_name/targetfs/c6accel_app
Copying kernel modules to target file system: /home/my_name/targetfs/c6accel_app/
Copying cmemk.ko
Copying dsplinkk.ko
Copying c6accel codec servers from /usr/local/dvsdk/c6accel_1_01_00_07
Copying c6accel test app from /usr/local/dvsdk/c6accel_1_01_00_07
Copying testfile from /usr/local/dvsdk/c6accel_1_01_00_07
```

Now I want to execute the C6accel sample.
So I reset target. **Oh no what is it?**

```
CMEM Range Overlaps Kernel Physical - allowing overlap
CMEM phys_start (0xc2000000) overlaps kernel (0xc0000000 -> 0xc4000000)
CMEMK Error: Failed to request_mem_region(0xc2000000, 18874368)
FATAL: Error inserting cmemk (/lib/modules/2.6.37/kernel/drivers/dsp/cmemk.ko): Bad address
```

Ok. I **ignore it** and enter login.

```
root@arago:/c6accel_app# ls
benchmarking.txt                 dsplinkk.ko
c6accel_app                      loadmodules_omapl138_c6accel.sh
c6accel_omapl138.x674            test_files
cmemk.ko
```

Ok!

```
root@arago:/c6accel_app# ./loadmodules_omapl138_c6accel.sh
    CMEMK module: built on Apr 12 2012 at 17:32:52
      Reference Linux version 2.6.37
      File /usr/local/dvsdk/linuxutils_2_26_02_05/packages/ti/sdo/linuxutils/cmem/src/module/cmemk.c
    CMEM Range Overlaps Kernel Physical - allowing overlap
    CMEM phys_start (0xc2000000) overlaps kernel (0xc0000000 -> 0xc4000000)
    CMEMK Error: Failed to request_mem_region(0xc2000000, 18874368)
    FATAL: Error inserting cmemk (/lib/modules/2.6.37/kernel/drivers/dsp/cmemk.ko): Bad address
```

Ooops! **Again same error!**

In the file loadmodules_omapl138_c6accel.sh I modified only one string

```
modprobe cmemk phys_start=0xC2000000 phys_end=0xC3200000 pools=20x4096 allowOverlap=1
```

So, finnaly I have

```
modprobe cmemk phys_start=0xC4000000 phys_end=0xC5200000 pools=20x4096 allowOverlap=1
```

Saved it. 
**Attempt 2.**

```
root@arago:/c6accel_app# ./loadmodules_omapl138_c6accel.sh
CMEMK module: built on Apr 12 2012 at 17:32:52
  Reference Linux version 2.6.37
  File /usr/local/dvsdk/linuxutils_2_26_02_05/packages/ti/sdo/linuxutils/cmem/src/module/cmemk.c
allocated heap buffer 0xc5000000 of size 0x11ec000
cmemk initialized
```

**Success!** Then I ran  ./c6accel_app

I was happy to see

```
Test for Arithmetic RTS functions successful
******************************************************************************
All tests done.
******************************************************************************

libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
```

**But early....**

```
root@arago:/c6accel_app# ls
Segmentation fault
```

Something broke. It has totally broken. 
What should I do in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casket easily opened....

Device has 64 mb of RAM. By this command

```
bootargs=console=ttyS2,115200n8 mem=64M root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.1.218:/home/my_name/targetfs ip=192.168.1.231
```

I simply say "Ok, kernel, take it all. It is all for you"

So... I got what I wanted: 32 mb - for kernel. Other 32 mb for CMEM. No segmentation faults more.